# Bootstrap Input Groups

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, less, searchbar

I am slightly new to web development and I am trying to teach myself. I am trying to make a searchbar with a dropdown, so far I have made it but I have a problem with the last button, it will be used as the search button. It doesnt fix on the left hand side, it just floats under the bar.

```
<div class="search">
      <div class="input-group">
               <div class="input-group-btn">
                 <button type="button" class="btn"><span class="fa-search"></span></button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                     Categories
                     <span class="caret"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                     <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                     <li class="divider"></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div><!-- /btn-group -->
               <input type="text" class="form-control">
               <button type="button" class="btn-search"><span class="fa-search">
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
            </span></button>

          </div><!-- ...search -->
```

Comment: post more code. And if possible jsfiddle for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would do a search with a dropdown- you are almost there.. just move the `input` after the `ul`

```
   <div class="col-lg-5">
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Categories <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /btn-group -->
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

link to [demo](http://www.bootply.com/vG6xshFmgH)